# Repository to save and retrieve NSArray from iCloud account

Tags: objective-c, icloud

I am currently storing and retrieving an NSArray in an "old school" fashion by doing encoding and decoding on the array of objects.

I want to move this storage to iCloud.

Is there a simple way to save an array of custom objects to iCloud and retrieve them?

PSEUDOCODE EXAMPLE

```
allocate mutable array

itereate 5 times
    create custom object

    add object to mutable array
end iteration

store mutable array to iCloud
```

...later on...

```
retrieve mutable array from iCloud

retrieve specific object from mutable array
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can save any type of data to iCloud, if iCloud is enabled on the device. You have a couple of options:

- If the data is small, use the key-value store. This works a lot like `NSUserDefaults`, but it syncs via iCloud. This is the easiest way but is the most restrictive option and is limited to no more than 1MB of data.
- Use the file API. Any file can be synced via iCloud by creating it locally and then using `NSFileManager` to make it "ubiquitous" (i.e. iCloud synced). On the receiving end you use `NSMetadataQuery` to locate files in iCloud, and then `NSFileManager` to download them and to get the latest version.
- Use `UIDocument`, which has its own semantics for saving and syncing data via iCloud.